# silent execution bug with processing standalone program

Tags: processing

I have been trying to use processing (3.0.2) as a lib to display video. You can see the beginning of my main class below. I am using Maven to build a fat .jar that I run on the command line. The program runs, does not freeze, and can be closed, but no video... (screenshot below) The problem is that happens totally silently: no warning, no crash.

I am totally sure that the video file is found by the program, since removing it triggers a `RuntimeException`.

**Edit:** Ok, so the file is found, but not the frames. The program is stuck trying to find a nonzero frame.

**Edit 2:** It seems it is in fact a GStreamer problem. Apparently, Processing does not support the GStreamer 1.x lineage. Installing GStreamer 0.1x as explained [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6856/processing-does-not-play-the-video-examples-that-come-with-it-black-screen) and [here](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/23), unfortunately did not work for me.

**Edit 3:** Trying with a basic example (code below), I see that the `Movie.read()` method is never triggered, although the `draw()` method is. Since there still are no errors or warnings, I guess it's a library problem. **Interestingly, this very same code works perfectly when executed as a .pde from the Processing IDE, so there must be a library there that I am lacking.** Any ideas??

My dependencies:

- core.jar
- video.jar
- jna.jar
- gstreamer-java.jar

System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (java version "1.8.0_77"), Processing 3.0.2 with video library installed through the processing IDE.

---

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.video.*;

public class TestMovie extends PApplet{

    Movie myMovie;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main(TestMovie.class.getName());
    }

    public void settings(){
        size(720, 480, FX2D);
    }

    public void setup() {
      //background(0);
        try{
            myMovie = new Movie(this, "red_45deg_284sec_500ml.mpg");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        myMovie.loop();
    }

    public void draw() {
      image(myMovie.get(), 0, 0);
      System.out.println("I'm drawing!");
    }

    // Called every time a new frame is available to read
    void movieEvent(Movie m) {
      try{
        m.read();
      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      System.out.println("new frame!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the behavior is expected: you're reading the video until the first frame which hasn't the size (0,0) and then you extract a single image from it and show that instead of the video (at least the code looks like this).

Comment: @Tom This is because due to interlacing, I want to show one big snapshot, and 4 smaller "screens" displaying the deinterlaced frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally got the movie playing, and it does not seem to be a library problem after all... For some mysterious reason, `movieEvent()` does not execute, most likely because no event is triggered. Using `Movie.available()` solved it as follows:

```
public class TestMovie extends PApplet{

    Movie myMovie;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main(TestMovie.class.getName());
    }

    public void settings(){
        size(720, 480, FX2D);
    }

    public void setup() {
      //background(0);
        try{
            myMovie = new Movie(this, "red_45deg_284sec_500ml.mpg");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        myMovie.loop();
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (myMovie.available()) {
            myMovie.read();
          }
          image(myMovie, 0, 0);
    }
}
```